# how to use http://randomuser.me/

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the tutorial said paste this code

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.randomuser.me/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

but what's next? I open console and see an array. How to retrieve the users' picture?

Comment: look at the array contents

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using another site

Comment: console.log(data.results[0].user.picture);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the data's contents.. it contains an object `results` which is an array with one object which has a user property which internally has the picture property so

```
data.results[0].user.picture
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HeXBz/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://api.randomuser.me/',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.results[0].user.picture);
                  }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is jsFiddle I added also name  http://jsfiddle.net/jpkeisala/4SZLk/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.randomuser.me/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $("#result").html(data.results[0].user.picture);
    $("img").attr("src",data.results[0].user.picture);
  }

});
```